# How do I impute values by factor levels using 'missForest'?

Tags: r, dataframe, imputation

I am trying to impute missing values in my dataframe with the non-parametric method available in `missForest`.
My data ([OneDrive link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AuvDWe9kv3DqjOcy7t2tEuDkLguB1A?e=zxCjeZ)) consists of one categorical variable and five continuous variables.

```
head(data)
               phylo     sv1 sv2      sv3 sv4 sv5
1 Phaon_camerunensis 6.03803  NA 5121.257  NA  70
2   Umma_longistigma 6.03803  NA 5121.257  NA  53
3   Umma_longistigma 6.03803  NA 5121.257  NA  64
4   Umma_longistigma 6.03803  NA 5121.257  NA  63
5      Sapho_ciliata 6.03803  NA 5121.257  NA  63
6     Sapho_gloriosa 6.03803  NA 5121.257  NA  63
```

I was successful at first using `missForest()`

`imp<- missForest(data[2:6])`

However, instead of aggregating over the whole data matrix (or vector? idk exactly) I would like to impute missing values by `phylo`.

I tried `data[2:6] %>% group_by(phylo) %>%` and `sapply(split(data[2:6], data$phylo)) %>%` but no success.

Any guess on how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run `missForest` for each group, you can use `group_map`:

```
imp <- df %>% group_by(phylo) %>% group_map(~ missForest(.))
```

To get only the first item from the result:

```
imp2 <- t(sapply(imp, "[[", 1))
```

Comment: The output is a long list of lists each with lenght 2: one dataframe and one single value, the OOBerror. Do you have any idea on how to select the list with lower OOBerror? I tried 'min(unlist(imp))' and 'order_number', however it worked only for the first [[1]] list. 'unlist(imp, recursive = FALSE)' also didn't work. I think the functions I used didn't work because the attributes of the lists all have the same name: ximp, the dataframe, and OOBerror.

Comment: I added how you can get the first item. Alternatively, you can use `map_df` for more tidyverse answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is not very clear, I assume that you want to impute subsets of your dataset according to the `phylo` variable. So for that, you need to split your dataset by you factor variable and apply the imputation function on each subset. This could be implemented using only R base functions:

```
# convert phylo to factor
data$phylo <- as.factor(data$phylo)

# split and impute according to each level 
data2 <-lapply(split(data,as.factor(data$phylon)), function(x) missForest::missForest(data))

# display the imputed dataset 
data2$ximp
```